# NET 6 - Cannot resolve 'service' from root provider because it requires scoped service 'xxContext'.' error only in Development environment

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-6.0, startup

I'm getting this error only in "Development" environment.

> Cannot resolve 'service' from root provider because it requires scoped service 'xxContext'.

This is my Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile(
    Path.Combine("configuration", $"configuration.{builder.Environment.EnvironmentName}.json")
    );

MicroserviceInit.SetConfigurationFromAzureKeyVault(builder.Environment.EnvironmentName, builder.Configuration);

var startup = new Startup(builder.Configuration);

startup.ConfigureServices(builder.Services);

var app = builder.Build();

startup.Configure(app, app.Services.GetRequiredService<TelemetryConfiguration>());

await app.UseOcelot(config => config.PreErrorResponderMiddleware = startup.PreErrorResponderMiddleware);

app.Run();
```

The error is thrown on `UseOcelot` and it comes from a Middleware in my Middlewares stack since one of them access a db context.

This is the StackTrace:

```
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.ValidateResolution(Type serviceType, IServiceScope scope, IServiceScope rootScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<UseMiddleware>b__0(RequestDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder.Build()
   at Ocelot.Middleware.OcelotPipelineExtensions.BuildOcelotPipeline(IApplicationBuilder app, OcelotPipelineConfiguration pipelineConfiguration)
   at Ocelot.Middleware.OcelotMiddlewareExtensions.CreateOcelotPipeline(IApplicationBuilder builder, OcelotPipelineConfiguration pipelineConfiguration)
   at Ocelot.Middleware.OcelotMiddlewareExtensions.<UseOcelot>d__2.MoveNext()
   at Ocelot.Middleware.OcelotMiddlewareExtensions.<UseOcelot>d__1.MoveNext()
   at Program.<<Main>$>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\...\.Gateway\Program.cs:line 26
```

Any ideas of what could be the problem?

Comment: AddOcelot(...) method is missing. This may be the problem.

Comment: It is done inside startup.ConfigureServices